# Segmentation fault in Fortran for lattice Boltzmann

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, fortran77

I am trying to code for lattice Boltzmann method in Fortran 77, while executing I get the Segmentation fault error. The code is as follows, let me know the mistake. I have tried to work out the logical errors but I have not found any mistake

```
implicit none
integer n,m,tstep,i,k,j
parameter (n=3,m=3,tstep=2)
real x(n),y(m),f1(n,m),f2(n,m),f3(n,m),f4(n,m)
real t(n,m),feq,c,alpha,omega,dx,dy,dt
dx=1.0d0
dy=1.0d0
dt=1.0d0
x(0)=0.0d0
y(0)=0.0d0
do 10 i=1,n
x(i)=x(i-1)+dx
y(i)=y(i-1)+dy  
10  continue

alpha=0.25d0
omega=1.0d0/((2.0d0*alpha)+0.5)
print*,'omega is', omega
do 20 j=0,m
   do 30 i=0,n
    t(i,j)=0.0d0
30     continue
20  continue    

do 40 j=0,m
  do 50 i=0,n
   f1(i,j)=0.25*t(i,j)
   f2(i,j)=0.25*t(i,j)
   f3(i,j)=0.25*t(i,j)
   f4(i,j)=0.25*t(i,j)

 50   continue
 40 continue

do 200 k=1,tstep

do 60 j=0,m
  do 70 i=0,n
    feq=0.25*t(i,j)
   f1(i,j)=(1.0d0-omega)*f1(i,j)+omega*feq
   f2(i,j)=(1.0d0-omega)*f1(i,j)+omega*feq
   f3(i,j)=(1.0d0-omega)*f1(i,j)+omega*feq
   f4(i,j)=(1.0d0-omega)*f1(i,j)+omega*feq
 70 continue
 60 continue

do 80 j=0,m
   do 90 i=0,n-1
f1(n-i,j)=f1(n-i-1,j)
f2(i-1,j)=f2(i,j)
 90 continue
 80     continue


do 100 i=0,n
  do 110 j=0,m-1
f3(i,m-j)=f3(i,m-j-1)
f4(i,j-1)=f4(i,j)
 110    continue
 100    continue



do 120 j=0,m
  f1(0,j)=0.5-f2(0,j)
  f3(0,j)=0.5-f4(0,j)
  f1(n,j)=0.0d0
  f2(n,j)=0.0d0
  f3(n,j)=0.0d0
  f4(n,j)=0.0d0
  120    continue
do 130 i=0,n
    f1(i,m)=0.0d0   
    f2(i,m)=0.0d0
    f3(i,m)=0.0d0
    f4(i,m)=0.0d0   
  f1(i,0)=f1(i,1)       
  f2(i,0)=f2(i,1)
 f3(i,0)=f3(i,1)
 f4(i,0)=f4(i,1)
  130   continue

do 140 j=0,m
   do 150 i=0,n
     t(i,j)=f1(i,j)+f2(i,j)+f3(i,j)+f4(i,j)
 150    continue
 140    continue

200 continue
open(unit=10,file='2dq4',status='unknown')

    do 230 j=0,m
        do 240 i=0,n
 write(10,*)x(i),y(j),t(i,j)    
 240    continue
 230    continue
   close(10)

stop
end
```

Comment: Try to reduce the problem into a [mcve] and include the full error message to the question.

Comment: Welcome. Pmease se the [Tour]. Try to create a smaller example. In most F77 compilers you can alredy use `END DO`. Use it, the code is much more readable. Fortran from this century, or at least Fortran 95 tends to be even more readable. Also, always use tag [tag:fortran].

Comment: Also learn to use the debugging features of your compiler. It will save you large amount of time. For gfortran it is '-g -fbacktrace -Wall -fcheck=all` and similar. Read the manual of your compiler.

Comment: I addition to comments above, usually with a segmentation fault you can get some idea of where it failed. Not necessarily exactly, but at least a clue. That clue would be a big help here.

Comment: array indexing in fortran starts at `1` not `0`.

Comment: It would be worth your while learning modern Fortran's array syntax.  You could then, for example, set every element in `t` to `0` in one statement !  Most of the other loops in the code shown could be replaced by array statements too.

Comment: @Brick It is failing in the part where I try to put the addition of t(i,j)=f1(i,j)+f2(i,j)+f3(i,j)+f4(i,j). When I am separately trying to print the addition of f1,f2,f3 and f4 the output is coming correctly in the terminal

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I did not understand your answer. What exactly do you want to convey

Comment: The comment by @HighPerformanceMark is essentially that F77 is terribly out of date, *even for those who use Fortran*. If you updated to a modern version (at least Fortran 90), then you'd not have some of these problems in addition to potentially getting better performance.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Fortran 77 start with index 1.  You are starting all of your loops at index 0.  That means that you are reading and writing out of bounds on all of your arrays.  It's only coincidence that you didn't crash sooner, since you made this error throughout your code.

As the comments note, using a more modern version of Fortran would give you new tools that might help avoid some of the complication of these loops. In addition, even for F77 code, your style is somewhat antiquated. Consider updating style and dialect.